# Запрос к MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать запрос к MySQL, чтобы вывелось значение, если  `in_nol = $id_alex и $id_max`?

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname, str, int, id_nol FROM datacenter WHERE surname = '$surname_alex' AND type = 'scholar' AND id_nol = '$id_alex', '$id_max'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, surname, str, int, id_nol FROM datacenter WHERE surname = '$surname_alex' AND type = 'scholar' AND id_nol IN ('$id_alex', '$id_max')
```

Оператор IN.

Comment: или так или просто OR, в данном случае вообще без разницы т.к. всего 2 id

Comment: Да, Alex. Вы абсолютно правы. "+" Вам)

Answer (score 0):

вроде говорится в условии об операторе "И", поэтому ни IN ни OR не подходит ) 
Достаточно простого AND

```
SELECT name, surname, str, int, id_nol FROM datacenter WHERE surname = '$surname_alex' AND type = 'scholar' AND ( id_nol ='$id_alex' AND id_nol = '$id_max')
```

Comment: Сами понимаете, уважаемый @draev, что Ваш запрос не вернет ни одной записи, т.к. id_nol не может одновременно равнятся двум разным величинам. Именно, либо OR, либо IN().